# agrupar y sumar cantidades dependiendo del estado

Tags: sql, sql-server, datatables

estoy creando una consulta para agrupar y sumar las cantidades si Payment_Per_Invoice es igual a verdadero.

así estoy estructurando mi QUERY:

```html
SELECT @InterfaseMXN as 'Tipo',A.Currency_Code,B.Supplier_Code,B.Name,

SUM(CASE WHEN C.Payment_Per_Invoice = 'False' THEN Amount END) as False,
SUM(CASE WHEN C.Payment_Per_Invoice = 'true' THEN Amount END) as True,

C.Payment_Type,C.Payment_Per_Invoice,B.Bank_Account_No,
C.Bank_ID,CONCAT (B.Supplier_Code,'',A.Invoice_No) AS 'Concepto'
FROM Accounting_v_AP_Invoice_e A
INNER JOIN  Common_v_Supplier_e B ON A.Supplier_No = B.Supplier_No
INNER JOIN  Common_v_Supplier_Accounting_e C ON C.Supplier_No = B.Supplier_No
WHERE A.Paid = '1' AND A.Currency_Code = 'MXN' AND Convert(DATE,A.Paid_Date) Between @Fecha_Inicio AND @Fecha_Fin
GROUP BY A.Currency_Code,B.Supplier_Code,B.Name,C.Payment_Type,C.Payment_Per_Invoice,B.Bank_Account_No,
C.Bank_ID,A.Invoice_No
ORDER BY A.Invoice_No
```

este es miersultado actual solo que no suma la cantidad y agrupa cuando Payment_Per_Invoice es igual a verdadero

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tu consulta no hace mucho sentido, por lo que no sirve como guía de lo que quieres hacer. Sería mejor que compartas datos de prueba y resultados esperados con base en esos datos de prueba. De preferencia, como código que podamos copiar y pegar.

Comment: ya esta editado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La siguiente consulta puede que no regrese el resultado esperado, pero es porque faltarían más datos para comprender que puede evitar que se agrupen correctamente.

La idea general, es que una vez que decides cual es el agrupamiento que seguirán ambas y cual es la diferencia entre el agrupamiento, puedes asignar las columnas según correspondan. Al agrupamiento en común se le agrega una constante (en este caso 1) y cuando se requiera un detalle, se asigna un número de fila (generado por `ROW_NUMBER()`). Una vez que tengas esa columna extra, puedes usarla en el GROUP BY para que siga la lógica que deseas.

```
--Primero necesitamos agregar una columna a la consulta para saber cuando agrupar por factura y cuando no.
--Para eso necesitamos una CTE (aunque podría haber sido una subconsulta)
WITH ctePagos AS(
    SELECT  @InterfaseMXN as 'Tipo',
            i.Currency_Code,
            s.Supplier_Code,
            s.Name,
            Amount,
            sa.Payment_Type,
            sa.Payment_Per_Invoice,
            s.Bank_Account_No,
            sa.Bank_ID,
            CONCAT (s.Supplier_Code,'',i.Invoice_No) AS 'Concepto',
            --Si es verdadero, damos un valor constante.
            --Si es falso, damos un valor distinto a cada fila.
            CASE WHEN sa.Payment_Per_Invoice = 'true' 
                THEN 1
                ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) END AS grupo
    FROM        Accounting_v_AP_Invoice_e       AS i
    INNER JOIN  Common_v_Supplier_e             AS s  ON i.Supplier_No  = s.Supplier_No
    INNER JOIN  Common_v_Supplier_Accounting_e  AS sa ON sa.Supplier_No = s.Supplier_No
    WHERE i.Paid = '1' 
    AND   i.Currency_Code = 'MXN' 
    AND   Convert(DATE,i.Paid_Date) Between @Fecha_Inicio AND @Fecha_Fin
)
--Seleccionamos todo de la CTE, por lo que ya podemos referenciar por los nombres asignados a las expresiones
--La columna "grupo" no está incluida en el SELECT, solo en el GROUP BY puesto que no nos interesa mostrarla
SELECT  Tipo,
        Currency_Code,
        Supplier_Code,
        Name,
        SUM( Amount) AS Importe,
        Payment_Type,
        Payment_Per_Invoice,
        Bank_Account_No,
        Bank_ID,
        Concepto
FROM ctePagos
GROUP BY Tipo,
         Currency_Code,
         Supplier_Code,
         Name,
         Payment_Type,
         Payment_Per_Invoice,
         Bank_Account_No,
         Bank_ID,
         Concepto,
         Grupo
ORDER BY Invoice_No;
```